# How can I save nicedit textarea formatted text in mysql database using js and php and retrieve the same formatted text

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, nicedit

I am using niceedit textarea and I am getting the content with html tags and even while retrieving the content returns with tag.
How can i receive only the formatted text?
My html code

```
<textarea  id="submenu_name"  cols="40" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
```

My JS

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"  type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);

 </script>


<script>
function Save()
{
var edit = new nicEditors.findEditor('submenu_name');
var name = edit.getContent();
}
</script
```

Comment: Got the answer was storing as htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES); Now Storing directly as the tags and its working like a charm.